# is it possible to pass custom parametrs to tween?

Tags: d3.js

from the documentation:

> ## transition.attrTween(name, tween)
>
> Transitions the value of the attribute with the specified name
>   according to the specified tween function. The starting and ending
>   value of the transition are determined by tween; the tween function is
>   invoked when the transition starts on each element, being passed the
>   current datum **d**, the current index **i** and the current attribute value
>   **a**, with the this context as the current DOM element. The return value
>   of tween must be an interpolator: a function that maps a parametric
>   value t in the domain [0,1] to a color, number or arbitrary value.

is it possible to pass the function "tween" also custom parameters, aside the d,i,a params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, I didn't find a way to do so.
but i did something else - instead of passing the variable to the tween function, i add the variable value to the HTML element as an attribute.
by this i could simply get the attribute on the tween function, and continue from there.
Thanks Pablo for the inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. You can use variables that are reachable from the tween function or embed the parameters in the data items.

Comment: "or embed the parameters in the data items." - means?

Comment: The argument `d` in the tween function is the data item. If this element is an object, you can add attributes to it: `d.custom_param = 0.5, d.custom_param2 = 1.3;` and use those parameters in the tween function.

Comment: yeah but it was impossible to get to "d" before it was called. but your answer inspired me to find the solution for this...